# SQL WHERE NOT EXISTS with string conditional

Tags: sql, string, integer, where-clause, exists

I'm trying to check if email doesn't exist in my database (MySQL, Node.js) , with a subquery like this:

```
register: async (data) => {

const rows = await db.promise().execute(

INSERT INTO Users (userEmail, userPassword) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT ${data.userEmail}, ${data.userPassword}) AS tmp
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT userEmail, userPassword 
                    FROM Users 
                    WHERE userEmail = {data.userEmail}) 
    LIMIT 1;

 );
      return rows;
    },
```

but it doesn't work

I'm already trying this request with id type INT.

My question is: do you think this request is possible with a string type?

Thanks a lot !

if i make a request with user already register on my database i get this error :

### {

```
"error": {
    "message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@beevora.fr, $2b$10$JnEjg8GIVXbJDAeGnm7ESey27yXkHMcvh2b/SKRQ.6UH5Tpvv.OVG\n      ' at line 2",
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@beevora.fr, $2b$10$JnEjg8GIVXbJDAeGnm7ESey27yXkHMcvh2b/SKRQ.6UH5Tpvv.OVG\n      ' at line 2"
},
"errMessage": "500 error server"
```

}##

and if user doesn't exist yet :

### {

```
"error": {
    "message": "Unknown column 'Lorris' in 'field list'",
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'Lorris' in 'field list'"
},
"errMessage": "500 error server"
```

}##

Comment: I'm also trying to change "=" with LIKE and it's still doesn't work

Comment: What language is the `${data.userEmail}` bit? PHP? If so, why doesn't the second `{data.userEmail}` bit have a dollar sign? Are you selecting one column and trying to insert into two (i.e. selecting "userEmail" but trying to insert into "userEmail, userPassword")?

Comment: *Doesn't work* tells completely nothing about the actual problem. Please, [clarify your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What database are you using? As I understood, you are trying to insert if no email exists and not do insert if email exists? For example in Postgres you can set up email as unique constraint and on conflict do nothing
Also you have mistakes in your query: you insert email and password, and select only email. Can you add exact error to your question?

Comment: I'm using Mysql and Node.js ,(sorry i'm beginner)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, and doesn't depend from your type - string or int. It worked with int because you send query:

```
select 1
```

For sql it means that have to insert 1 as int type
If you setup string you send query to database select like this:

```
select mymail@gmail.com
```

Database understands select column with name mymail@gmail.com should search column mymail@gmail.com - and it doesn't find any column.

Correct is:

```
 select 'mymail@gmail.com'
```

With ''

But it's wrong to insert into queries raw values from user - you will have SQL Injection vulnerability and anyone who is familiar with this injection can access to any data and insert anything to your database. You can read more at [SQL Injection wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

For make this work correctly you should

1. Create table with unique constraint on email, like this

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password_hash VARCHAR(256)
)
```

You need id for references to other tables and I would recommend you to store not raw password but it's hash (sha-1 for example) to prevent password stealing in case of getting access to your database
2. make query like this

```js
dbconn.query("INSERT INTO USERS (email, password_hash) VALUES (?,?)",
            [email, passwordHash], (err, result) => {
 if(err){
   //1169 or 1062 error code. See error reference below
   if(err.code == DUPLICATE_ERROR_CODE){ 
     notifyUserThatEmailExists();
     return;
   } else {
     throw err;
   }
   success();
 } 
}
```

[Error Reference MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_dup_key)

In this example email and password hash parameters will be set as parameters and will always interpreted by database as parameters, not as column names, and this query will be protected from SQL injection

Comment: thank you very much, it is very interesting and enriching. I will do your method in the future! :)